# shadowing parameters by local variables?

Tags: javascript, scope

(edit) I found out there's another post: "[Where are arguments positioned in the lexical environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208843/where-are-arguments-positioned-in-the-lexical-environment)" that is directly related to my question.

---

When I was reading "[You Don't Konw JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/apA.md#parameter-scope)", I did some experiments to shadow parameters by declaring local variables in the function, and then I met some weird situations that I am not able to explain, so I posted my code here to seek some help.

Please take a look at the "**case 2**" of the following code, and see if you can tell what's happening, thanks.

My questions: (in "**case 2**")

- Are "parameter list" and "function body" in the same scope ?

  - if so, `var id = 5` should be considered a "redeclaration",
    parameter `id` would be updated by the redeclaration,
    but it's NOT, why ?   (see: (***) below)
  - if they're not in the same scope, why can't we shadow
    the (outer) parameter `id` with a local "let", like we
    do in a "for-loop" ?  (see: (*) below)

```js
const { log } = console;

let count = 0;

// (*)
// ⭐ "initialization block" in a for-loop
// ---------------------------------------
//   ╭──init───╮
for ( let i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {

    // ⭐ for-loop body (block scope) and the "initialization block"
    //    are in different scopes, so we can "shadow" the outer `i`
    //    with a local "let" without any problem.
    let i = 1;
    
    log(i);                    // 1, 1, 1
    if (++count > 3) break;    // prevent infinite loop
}

// ⭐ case 1: (alters parameter directly)
// ---------------------------------------
// • parameter `id` is closed over by `defaultID`.
//
//                ╭─── parameter list ───╮
function doUpdate(id, defaultID = () => id) {
    id = 5;                  // ✅ parameter `id` updated (see (**) below)
    log( defaultID() );
}

// (**)
doUpdate(3);                 // ✅ 5

// ⭐ case 2: (shadows parameter by local "var")
// ----------------------------------------------
//
//                    ╭─── parameter list ───╮
function doesntUpdate(id, defaultID = () => id) {

    // ----------------------
    //  ❓ weird situation ❓
    // ----------------------
    
    // ❗ 2.1: can't shadow parameters by "let" variables
    // ----------------------------------------------------------
    // let id = 5;
    //     ^^
    // ⛔ SyntaxError: Identifier 'id' has already been declared
    // ----------------------------------------------------------

    log( defaultID() );      // 3

    // ⭐ 2.2 use "var" instead:
    // -------------------------
    
    var id = 5;              // ❗ this do shadow parameter `id`
    log(id);                 // 5

    log( defaultID() );      // 3
    
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    // ⭐ are "parameter list" and "function body" in the same scope ❓
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //   • if so, `var id = 5` should be considered a "redeclaration",
    //     parameter `id` would be updated by the redeclaration, 
    //     but it's NOT, why ❓   (see: (***) below)
    //     (Q: is parameter `i` a "var" ?) 
    // 
    //   • if they're not in the same scope, why can't we shadow 
    //     the (outer) parameter `id` with a local "let", like we
    //     do in a "for-loop"❓  (see: (*) above)
    //
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------

}

// (***)
doesntUpdate(3);             // ❗ (parameter `id` is not updated)
```

Comment: in the "case 2", the local variable `id` is `5` alright, but the original parameter `id` is "closed over" by `defaultID()`, which shows the original parameter `id` is still `3`, not `5`, that's why it's not updated (by the local variable).

Comment: It's probably a similar "half scope" as you get with `for`. (There is a great [video](https://youtu.be/Nzokr6Boeaw) about the `for` case by the way, it gives a glimpse what goes on behind the scenes and that a "scope" is an over-simplification). Welcome to the JavaScript iceberg :)

Comment: The phenomenon in "case 2" is called a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to scope. It has to do with the re-declaration of a variable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#description:

> Duplicate variable declarations using `var` will not trigger an error, even in strict mode, and the variable will not lose its value, unless another assignment is performed.

This is exactly what you are doing in **case 2**: you re-declare `id` with the `var` keyword and you assign it a new value.

The scope is simply the function [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope).

These examples might clarify things concerning function scope. They illustrate the fact that OP's `defaultID` function simply creates a closure over `id` and when a new variable `id` is created, the reference in the `defaultID` function can no longer be accessed in the body of `doesntUpdate`.

Control example

```
const main = () => {
  const x = 1;

  const fn = (
    fnX,
    adder = () => { // Variable "adder" contains a function which creates
                    // its own function scope with a closure over "fnX".
      fnX = fnX + 2;
    },
    multiplier = () => { // Same here.
      fnX = fnX * 2;
    },
  ) => {
    console.log('fnX (before)', fnX);

    const added = adder();
    fnX = 5;
    const multiplied = multiplier();

    console.log('fnX (after)', fnX);
    console.log('fnX === x', fnX === x);
  };

  fn(x);
};

main();
```

Example with `var` re-declaration:

```
const main = () => {
  const x = 1;

  const fn = (
    fnX,
    adder = () => {
      fnX = fnX + 2;
    },
    multiplier = () => {
      fnX = fnX * 2;
    },
  ) => {
    console.log('fnX (before)', fnX);

    const added = adder();
    var fnX = 5; // fnX is now a "new" variable, it replaced the one
                  // with the same name which was created as an argument.
                  // "adder" and "multiplier" still operate on the
                  // initial variable but that variable can no longer
                  // be referenced in the body of "fn".
    const multiplied = multiplier();

    console.log('fnX (after)', fnX);
    console.log('fnX === x', fnX === x);
  };

  fn(x);
};

main();
```

NOTE: I created a `main` function so we don't have to wonder about global or module context.

Comment: It's not as simple as that I'm afraid. `var` redeclarations are NOT simply ignored, if you have assignment attached with your redeclaration, the assignment is **applied**, for example: `var x = 1; var x = 2; console.log(x);`, and the output will be `2`, so this is a proof that `var` redeclarations are not simply ignored, actually the assignments are still applied, and the original `var` will be updated to new valules.

Comment: And to my understanding, it's **not simply** the "function scope", there's a so called "[parameter scope](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/2nd-ed/scope-closures/apA.md#parameter-scope)" involved in the `function` declaration, but that's exactly where I got totally confused, and that's why I posted this question.

Comment: "the assignment is applied" Yes, that is what I said and what the documentation says.

Comment: " it's not simply the "function scope" ...   Scope does not matter in your example.

Comment: Could you explain what does matter in the example?

Comment: @Sébastien No, but I was confused about that at first too. Check the `defaultID` function which is defined _within the parameter scope_ (not function scope) and closes over `id`. Since it still returns 3 at the end, this shows that it can't be a redeclaration because we now have two distinct variables, one with value 3 and one with value 5.

Comment: `var` does not do anything magical, nor does the function scope. The defaultID function does not return anything "at the end", it saves the initial value, whenever you print it: it is the initial value.
`var` allows you to redeclare  a variable, or to say it differently: to delcare a variable with the same name as a variable existing in the same scope, and assign it whatever value you want.

Comment: @CherryDT
see examples

Comment: I'm very confused now because you just added an example that proves _my_ point, that it's not simply a redeclaration but creating a new variable in a different (inner) scope, otherwise it would be the same `id` in both parameter scope and function scope.

Comment: What it boils down to is this - imo very legitimate - question: If the parameter scope and the function scope are separated (as the OP's as well as your own example demonstrated), then why would `let` and `const` fail to declare a new `id` in the inner scope and complain about it already being declared?

Comment: Also, 'Variable "adder" contains a function which creates its own function scope with a closure over "fnX".' is correct but misleading, because `adder` never declares any variables in its own function scope. It simply closes over the `fnX` in `fn`'s parameter scope. The comment makes it sound as if the assignment of `fnX = fnX + 2` would implicitly create another variable in a different scope...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Gish_gallop

Comment: I don't see how this is related. It's a very straight forward issue. If the scopes were simply two regular separate scopes like anywhere else in JS, `var` should declare a new variable, `defaultID` should keep returning the original value, and `let` and `const` should work too. If it were the simply the same scope, `var` would just redeclare the variable, `defaultID` should return the updated value, and `let` and `const` should fail with "already declared". However, here we have a mix of the two behaviors.

Comment: It's related as in I don't have the time.